# Exporting InfoPath form to PDF when user's display is at 150%

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, infopath, pdf

I have a button added to my list view that opens SP2013 list data into a new InfoPath form using the InfoPath 2013 client. That form then has a button which programmatically exports the form into a PDF document.

I have one user who sets their display to 150%, and as a result the PDF exports with 1/3 of the document cut off. Changing the display back to 100% in Control Panel fixes the issue, but the user wants their display at 150% and doesn't want to have to change it each time they need a PDF. This person is running Windows 7 (Ultimate, I believe, but it could be Professional) 32-bit. I'm able to duplicate the issue, however, on my 64-bit Win7 Pro machine.

This may be a question for the Super User or SE exchanges, not sure. It's not specific to SharePoint, but SP2013 is the platform it's all launching from. The code behind the button does a lot of setting variables and such, but here's the relevant  part:

```
//Do the work -- switch to the PDF view then export it as a PDF file.

Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.View currentView = this.CurrentView;
this.CurrentView.Export(@fileLocation + fileName + ".pdf", ExportFormat.Pdf);
```

**Has anyone run into this issue before, or know of a way to supercede the display setting when exporting an InfoPath form?**

**Edit:** If this question belongs elsewhere, please let me know which SE to put it on. I didn't find anything specific to InfoPath.

Comment: Can you post a code that *programmatically exports the form into PDF*?

Comment: What is the client OS? Windows 8.1 or older?

Comment: @AzizKabyshev - updated question with those details. It's Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, default 100% scaling corresponds to 96 so-called **OS DPI**, and 150% gives 144 DPI ([see "Writing DPI-Aware Desktop and Win32 Applications" @ MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#appendix_b_optimal_configuration_examples)).

> Applications that do not account for DPI and do not adjust for the
>   larger font and UI sizes can cause various classes of issues. This
>   section describes the most common categories of issues and shows
>   examples that illustrate them. The categories of high DPI issues
>   include:
>
> - Clipped UI Elements or Text
>     ...

Also, from that doc:

> The formula to calculate the effective resolution is:
>
> `Effective Resolution = Physical Resolution / (DPI/96)`

So it seems logical why 33% of view pixels are clipped.

---

What you could do is:

- If elements of the Infopath view have size set in pixels (`px`), experiment with setting those to other units - inches or centimeters, or `auto`
- Check if that behavior was somehow changed by updates. `DPI` term is mentioned at least in [KB2817430 (SP1 for Office 2013)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2817430). But it's unlikely, those are more about Infopath interface, not views
- File this as *known issue* and do nothing